# How to get credit memo collection from last 2 weeks in magento2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, creditmemo

I see that `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CreditmemoFactory` has createByOrder and createByInvoice methods and I cannot do `->create()->addAttributeToFilter('created_at'`

I would like to get the credit memos from the last 2 weeks **regardless of when the order was placed**. So I cannot do `$order->getCreditmemosCollection()`.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to load all credit memos created in the last 2 weeks, regardless of when the order was created. Have you looked at using the [service contracts](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-contracts.html) for loading your data?

You'd need to inject the following 2 classes into your constructor. The `SearchCriteriaBuilder` class for creating the search criteria (filter), and the `CreditmemoRepositoryInterface` for loading the credit memos.

```php
\Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoRepositoryInterface
\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
```

Build up your search criteria:

```php
$yourDate = '2017-01-01';
$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
    ->addFilter(
        'created_at',
        $yourDate,
        'gt'
    )->create()
;
```

Then get the credit memos from the repository:

```php
$creditmemos = $this->creditmemoRepository
    ->getList($searchCriteria)
    ->getItems()
;
```

From there you should be able to loop through the array, loading whatever data it is that you need:

```php
foreach ($creditmemos as $creditmemo) {
    echo $creditmemo->getAdjustment();
}
```

You can see the available methods to call on the `$creditmemo` in the class `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\CreditmemoInterface`.

Answer (score 3):

You can include only `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Collection` in your constructor, in this case, you can use directly "addFieldToFilter" function without declaring or include `searchCriteria`

Your construct

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Creditmemo\Collection $creditmemoCollection,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->creditmemoCollection = $creditmemoCollection;
    ...
}
```

And your function

```
public function yourfunction() {
    ...
    $collection = $this->creditmemoCollection;
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('gt' => $yourdate));

    foreach($collection as $creditmemo):
        ...
        $data = $creditmemo->getData();
        ....
    endforeach;
}
```